# Efficient, vectorizable, Gram-Schmidt (or QR decomposition where we care about the signs of the Q matrix columns)

Tags: numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, jax

I'm working on a problem that involves orthogonalizing many sets of vectors. And at the end of the day, it needs to be jax.grad-able for my purposes as it's also going to go into a gradient descent algorithm.

The function in general would look something like this

INPUTS:

A (..., M, N)

- input tensor where the first unknown number of indices enumerate the different matrices we want the QR decomp of. For each matrix, the columns are the vectors we want to make orthonormal (same as the standard input scheme)

RETURNS

Q (..., M, N)

- the output of a continuous Gram-Schmidt or similar procedure

Initially I was just going to use the jax.np.qr function and use the Q matrix. However, the quantities I'm calculating using this decomposition are very sensitive to the signs of the Q matrix columns. It is very important that the output is a smooth function of the input. (The result is something I'm going to be Fourier transforming)

My problem stems (I think) from the fact that the qr function outputs are not smooth functions of the input. Small changes to the input matrices result in Q matrices that are very close to each other up to a sign. But this won't give me the behavior that I'm expecting. (I'm computing wannier functions which are gauge dependent quantities and these signs are part of that gauge choice)

Looking through the documentation, I don't see any keywords that would obviously solve this issue. I was wondering if anyone has done something similar before, or knows where I can find something like this.

I can get something to work using a hand-written standard Gram-Schmidt procedure, but this function is going to be called many, many times on a fairly large mesh of matrices. So if a major library already has something like this implemented it's going to be way better than any bad code that I can write...

Comment: To attract answers, consider including example code that demonstrates the problem you are having with `jax.np.qr`.

Comment: The QR decomposition is not unique. There are other algorithms you can try to implement. Or maybe find a function that does the QR decomposition while letting your choose the algorithm. Here is the wiki [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition).

Comment: Looking online, the only vectorized solution I found for Gram Schmidt is the one in the tensorflow probability repo. https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/v0.23.0/tensorflow_probability/python/math/gram_schmidt.py#L28 You could maybe adapt that to JAX.

Comment: I also found that method, and tensorflow even has a jax module, but unfortunately its not jax.grad-able. I think I'll just rewrite it by hand with the proper jax loops to get it to work